# Reversing matrix multiplication

Tags: matrices

Consider an rectangular matrix $B$ whose dimension is $m\times n$, an square matrix $D$ (not necessarily invertible) with $n\times n$ dimension and the product
$BD=C$.

If I know $B$ and $C$, it is possible to obtain $D$?

I think the "standard" answer is "no", but there may be an method for this porpose (feeling hopefull).

Comment: I believe this just means that there is not one such unique $D$, but a family of solutions that would satisfy the equation. Yes, you should be able to find one (or all of them parametrized by some free variables) by some standard methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $rank(B) = n$ (which implies $n \leq m$), then $B$ has a left inverse $A$ ($n\times m$ matrix such that $AB = I_n$.) Then $D = AC$.

Or you may think like this: if $rank(B) =n$, then the columns of $B$ are linearly independent. The first column of $D$ is a solution of the linear system $BX = col_1(C)$, and $col_1(C)$ can be written in a unique way as a linear combination of the columns of $B$, hence $col_1(D)$ is determined. Same for the rest of the columns.

Start with the $m \times 2n$ matrix $[B | C]$ and perform row operations to get the $rref(B)$; at that point the matrix will be $\begin{bmatrix}I_n & D \\ 0 & 0  \end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: If $rank(B) \neq n$, then $D$ is not determined; in fact, no column of $D$ is uniquely determined.

Comment: I computed the rank of B on my application and it's exacly equal to n, thank you miss

Answer (score 0):

The map $L(D) = BD$ is linear, you are trying to solve $L(D) = C$ which can
be solved by taking a basis and solving the resulting linear system.